# Use 'on sent ok' action hook for two actions - Contact Form 7/WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to use the `on sent ok` action hook for two actions 1) to track the email adress and 2) to send the user to a thank you page. I tried adding this into the 'Additional Settings' section on the Contact Form 7 panel but I am not sure if it works correctly. At least I got different results when using it with two different forms.

```
on_sent_ok: "fnTransaction('Contacted', 'userid=' + [your-email]);"

on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://xxxxx.com/thank-you');"
```

Is it OK to use the action hook twice or can I combine this somehow? I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

couldn't you just call `location.replace('http://xxxxx.com/thank-you');` inside the `fnTransaction()`-function?

**edit:**

write a new function that combines both:

```
on_sent_ok: "mySentOkFunction('Contacted', 'userid=' + [your-email]);"

function mySentOkFunction(param1, param2){
    fnTransaction(param1, param2);
    location.replace('http://xxxxx.com/thank-you');
}
```

Comment: The fnTransaction() is provided by a third-party PPC company so I cannot really edit this function unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Contact Form 7 but have you tried this:

```
on_sent_ok: "function(){ fnTransaction('Contacted', 'userid=' + [your-email]);location.replace('http://xxxxx.com/thank-you');}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
on_sent_ok: "fnTransaction('Contacted', 'userid=' + [your-email]); location.replace('http://xxxxx.com/thank-you');"
```

Here location.replace didn't work, so I'm using:

```
location = 'http://xxxxx.com/thank-you';
```

This would be the final code:

```
on_sent_ok: "fnTransaction('Contacted', 'userid=' + [your-email]); location = 'http://xxxxx.com/thank-you';"
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean approach is to use the hook [`wpcf7_contact_form_properties`](http://hookr.io/filters/wpcf7_contact_form_properties/) in a custom plugin, here is the plugin:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Multiple WPCF7's on_sent_ok
Plugin URI: http://kadimi.com/wpcf7-javascript-programmatically
Description: Use WPCF7's on_sent_ok many times.
Author: Nabil Kadimi
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://kadimi.com/
*/

function se_21402617_wpcf7_properties( $properties, $contact_form_obj, $unused ){
    $properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .= 
        "\n"
        . 'on_sent_ok: "console.log(1);"' . "\n"
        . 'on_sent_ok: "console.log(2);"' . "\n"
        . 'on_sent_ok: "console.log(3);"' . "\n"
    ;
    return $properties;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_contact_form_properties', 'se_21402617_wpcf7_properties' , 10, 2 );
```

As you can see in the plugin code, I used `on_sent_ok` 3 times.

You can filter which form is affected by inspecting the `$contact_form_object`.

#### Source:

Code is derived from [my blog post here](http://kadimi.com/wpcf7-javascript-programmatically).